# How do I populate a Drop-down list , dynamically, based on a previous selection - using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic, drop-down-menu

Firstly, forgive me, if I am (seemingly) repeating a question that has been answered on this site (or else where on the net) before. I am from an R&D(C++) background and new to web development; but usually I get answers pretty quickly, but this particular problem is perplexing me.

Thanks for all your time, in advance.

### The Context

I have a simple web page *(a form)* where the user enters simple details, and stores a record in a MySQL DB, using PHP. There are many tables in this DB, *TWO of which are used to DYNAMICALLY populate two drop-down selection lists(HTML controls)*.

Populating the first drop down list works fine. The second one though, is to be populated, based on a selection made in the first drop-down list.

Both drop-down lists get their data from a SQL query.

### The Challenge

After 1/2 day of scanning this site and about 10 different sites on AJAX, Javascript, PHP etc- I haven't found a solution, and my little project(which I only got accepted on this evening), is due for completion tomorrow midday!

So, my challenge, is that I cannot- for the life of me- find a way to use AJAX(only started using it this evening!) or any other web technology, to populate the second drop-down list, with data from a table in MySQL.

the code is something along the lines of:

```
<select name="listDevices" id="listDevices"         
onchange="$('#brands').load('populateBrands.php?nID=1');    "         
title="<?php echo ucfirst($row_DevicesRec['de_name']); ?>">
<?php

do {  
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_DevicesRec['de_name']?>"><?php echo $row_DevicesRec['de_name']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_DevicesRec = mysql_fetch_assoc($DevicesRec));
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($DevicesRec);
    if($rows > 0) {
        mysql_data_seek($DevicesRec, 0);
        $row_DevicesRec = mysql_fetch_assoc($DevicesRec);
    }
?>
</select>
</label></td>
</tr>

<tr valign="baseline">
    <td height="121" align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
        <div align="left" class="style3 style3" >Brands</div>
    </td>
<td><label>     
</label>
<label><br />
<select name="brands" id="brands">
</select>
<br />
</label></td>
```

where, "brands" is the ID field of the 2nd drop-down list.

### The Solution(s)??

Add code to the `"OnChange"` event handler of the first drop down list. Right? Right! Now, for the life of me, I'm unable to figure out a way to use a AJAX .load(or any other) function to call my PHP file, which will "dynamically create" the SELECT drop-down list control and populate it.

Now.. I know this has been dealt with, but I do not believe, it is sufficiently understood- due to the complexities of mixing HTML, Javascript, PHP and now AJAX... ALL in one source file! (So , forgive me for my ignorance and please help me, if you can).

Where am I going wrong????
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem as far as I can tell seems to be that you're always calling `populateBrands.php?nID=1` - if everything else is working correctly, your second dropdown will always contain the same elements, as if the first item in the first dropdown is selected.

To remedy this you'll need to make it find the necessary ID to use as the GET parameter that the AJAX calls, so something like this:

```
onchange="$('#brands').load('populateBrands.php?nID=' + $('#listDevices').val());"
```

This will get the value of the first select box and pass it as a parameter to the PHP script, instead of always using "1".
However, for this to work, you'll probably need to make sure the values of the first dropdown have ID's as their values instead of the names (unless you can get this to work reliably with `populateBrands.php`.

Currently you have this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row_DevicesRec['de_name']?>"><?php echo $row_DevicesRec['de_name']?></option>
```

You'll probably need to change that to something like this, depending on your data:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row_DevicesRec['de_id']?>"><?php echo $row_DevicesRec['de_name']?></option>
```

Hope that helps. If nothing is working, though (i.e. your second dropdown isn't populating at all), post what returns when you call `populateBrands.php?nID=1` and maybe I can help diagnose.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for responding! Always appreciate folks taking time to share their wisdom. I have an update - of GOOD NEWS! I will share that through the answer-your-question option(??).  But I can see exactly where you are coming from, regarding the ID being hard-coded as a POST var. did that intentionally, as part of my debugging and testing processes. I finally managed to find a solution by someone on this site - which I managed to emulate by modifiying my code, and it worked! Yay! Will post my code(may help someone one) and link to the original solution. Thanks  SharkofMirkwood.

Comment: Actually, I feel this question is not welcome on this site(been voted down). Probably because there've been other similar posts. Will leave it at this.  Thanks to anyone who genuinely tried to help me.  Truth wins out.. Oummm

Comment: Ah okay, well glad to know you solved it! And sorry if I insulted your intelligence by thinking you hardcoded the ID by accident, haha.
Happy hacking ;)